# Storing fixed number of items in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I will be storing draw numbers (1-60) in fixed values and fixed order.

> One draw has 4 numbers
>   another has 6 numbers
>   and another 2 numbers

My idea was to separate each draw type in a separate sql table. The question is, would it be optimal to store the numbers in a single column separated by a delimiter....

```
ID(int) | numbers(varchar)
```

or store each number in a separate column instead?

```
ID(int) | num1(tinyint) | num2(tinyint) | num3(tinyint) | num4(tinyint)
```

I won't be needing to search for the numbers when they're stored.

Comment: There is a third option.  `DrawID, NumberID, NumberValue`.  This means that each draw can have many rows, one for each number that you are storing.  Whatever you do, do *not* use your first option.  Never compress a list of values into a string so that you can store it in a single field.  Each value should always be store in it's own place.  Either it's own field in the same row, or it's own field in another row.  But never a string list.  Yikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't ever need to search for them separately or retrieve them separately, then they are just one opaque "blob" from the database perspective and you won't be violating the [principle of atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity) and the 1NF by storing them into single filed.

**But**, just because that's the case now, doesn't mean it won't change in the future. So at least use the second option. Also, this would allow the DBMS to enforce the **integrity of domain** and ensure these are actually numbers and just any strings.

However, to future-proof your data, I'd go even further and use the following structure:

[image]

In addition to treating numbers in the uniform way and avoiding many NULLs, it'll also allow you to easily vary the max. number of numbers if that ever becomes necessary. I suspect querying will also be easier in this structure.

BTW, if there are no `(other fields)` and a draw cannot exist without at least one number, you can dispense with the DRAW table altogether and just use DRAW_NUMBER.

Comment: I cannot understand the schema

Answer (score 1):

separate columns ([Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization))

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to search for the numbers (i.e. find which draw has a certain number), then I would store the numbers in the same field.

**CLARIFICATION**

He said it himself, he's just storing data and doesn't need to do any sort of operation on it.  What that data is doesn't matter.  It happens to be between 2 to 6 numbers, but that's irrelevant.  There is no reason to put them in separate columns unless you need it for some reason.

What I would do is to use only one table, with three columns: id, draw_type, numbers

It's much easier to work with than 3 different tables with 3 to 7 columns each.

Comment: If you don't want people to -1 this, you might want to explain the relative merrits and costs of this approach.  I would personally say to *never* do this.  It's a false economy today with a technical debt for the future.